# I don't understand the Dojo documentation

Tags: dojo

I'm a beginner in dojo. First of all is everything javascript based? For example to create a form I have to use JavaScript or HTML tags?

Also I cannot understand their documentation and tutorials. It's very confusing.
Is there a proper website (other then dojo itself) that has good tutorials?

Comment: Why are you beginning with Dojo? Yes, it is a javascript framework. So you will need to have experience with Javascript to work with it. I don't think there are website that explain Dojo better than the Dojo website itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dojo's components's (widgets) in two ways. Programmatic and declaritive. The programmatic way (what you are talking about) is by defining widgets through the use of javascript. With declaritive you can define them using HTML markup. David Walsh has a nice short writeup and if you search for "declaritive programmatic dojo" you'll find some questions and answers on the matter:

- https://davidwalsh.name/dojo-widget
- [Difference between programmatically vs declaratively created widgets in dojo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440556/difference-between-programmatically-vs-declaratively-created-widgets-in-dojo)
- [Declarative coding or programmatic coding in Dojo Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130354/declarative-coding-or-programmatic-coding-in-dojo-projects)
- [Declarative or programatic approach in DOJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484583/declarative-or-programatic-approach-in-dojo)

If you're having trouble with the tutorials on the Dojo website, i suspect you're better off, first diving into some basic beginner javascript tutorials before trying to learn a framework like Dojo. I concur with the comment Ferry made on your question, there are no better resources than the actual Dojo website. I recommend following every tutorial, starting with the Hello Dojo tutorial and working your way up so that you don't miss out on the basic concepts which you'll need when you read the harder tutorials. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: dojo is javascript-based platform that provide you with a basic javascript library and a bunch of basic widgets (UI controls like button, dialogue, layouts,...), and some extra things. However, you don't really have to use dojo all the time: you still can use dojo to manipulate a html form button; it's just dojo button comes with extra functionalities and might save you some time.

For the second question, I agree with iH8  that dojo website is the best place to start. There are three different ways dojo websites can help you:

- Look at the tutorial: Basic steps on how to set it up and use provided functionalities as-is
- Look at the[toolkit api](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/): This provides a very detailed view of dojo javascript object (See what extra things you can do with dojo objects)
- Look at the nightly[test](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/): I found this very helpful in term of showing me what can be done outside of the tutorial (i.e. how to use things you found in the api)

Other than these, you can look at existing implementation to learn about the toolkit.

Basically, this is how I am learning Dojo. Without more-specific questions, it's hard to tell what is confusing about the tutorial. I would recommend you give it a try and post a question: everyone here will be willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with some video tutorial like [this](https://youtu.be/lU2u7hW-MSY?list=PLkMd51xTELZLc3PK_A7KCTj_veHwGZuuF).

When you understand the concept, you can try to copy and paste some code from Dojo documentation tutorials or Reference Guide, because all books are out-of-date.

Also you may find some useful information on IBM-related sites like [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ground/) because IBM invested in Dojo and uses it for its products.

If you have enough resources ($) you can take participation in Workshops (sitepen.com/workshops)